# Passenger NGINX module Failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

At one point I've had everything running fine on my system with NGINX, Rails, and Passenger.

Yesterday I did a fresh install of Passenger, and now `passenger-install-nginx-module` fails.

```
    /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.13/ext/nginx/../common/libpassenger_common.a /.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.13/ext/nginx/../common/libboost_oxt.a -lstdc++ -       lpthread -lm -lpcre -lssl -lcrypto -lz
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_pcre_free_study", referenced from:
  _ngx_pcre_free_studies in ngx_regex.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [objs/nginx] Error 1
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

This exact problem was posted yesterday on ServerFault, but I think it's more likely to be answered here (I apologize if that is a problem).

https://serverfault.com/questions/399304/cannot-install-phusion-passenger-3-0-13-with-nginx-1-2-1

Thanks for any help.

Comment: do you have libpcre installed?  Do you have it enabled?

Comment: I'm running a Mac OS and have installed pcre through brew...I can't find libpcre (at least not with brew). If I have what I need, how do I ensure it is enabled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see NGINX has a [ticket](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/94#comment:9) for this that has been closed, but the solution did not work for me.

I did, however, get NGINX up and running again with Passenger by running a customized installation. It's obviously a compatibility issue with versions 2 and up.

First I just pulled down the NGINX source (1.0.15).

In my /usr/local

```
wget http://www.nginx.org/download/nginx-1.0.15.tar.gz nginx_source
```

Untar

```
 tar -xvz nginx-1.0.15.tar.gz
```

Then run the passenger installation. Choosing option 2 (Customized Instalation)

```
sudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

There it prompts for where the source is `/usr/local/nginx-1.0.15` and where you want it installed `/usr/local/nginx` (in my case).

Everything worked fine from there, anyone know of any real fixed for NGINX 2, please let me know.

Comment: The problem may be with the version of pcre that is installed. Glad you got something working

Comment: Great! Thank you! I just spent two hours trying to build it on mac os x lion

Comment: You should choose /usr/local as installation dir though

Comment: @mgaughan Thanks dude, though that I added an additional option --with-ld-opt='-L /usr/local/lib' to configure to works. P.S. I'm on a Hackintosh, I don't know if it's relevant or not.

Answer (score 6):

```
brew install pcre
```

when config step also add

```
--with-pcre --with-ipv6 --with-ld-opt=-L/usr/local/lib
```

it also use with-ld-opt as homebrew,it's not perfect.

also can take a look at http://wiki.nginx.org/InstallOptions

Comment: The `--with-ld-opt` flag you mentioned was what fixed it for me.